# Django Rest Framework read file upload

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to read the contents of a csv file and save into a model.

```
# MODEL
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    datafile = models.FileField(upload_to=file_path_name)


# SIGNAL TO READ THE FILEUPLOAD INSTANCE
@receiver(post_save, sender=FileUpload)
def fileupload_post_save(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    with open(instance.datafile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
            print row
```

The serializer file.

```
# SERIALIZER
class FileUploadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
    model = FileUpload
```

When I upload the file, appears this error.

```
Got a `TypeError` when calling `FileUpload.objects.create()`. 
This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `FileUpload.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the FileUploadSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception text was: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FieldFile found.
```

The open() method should not open an instance of this FileField file?

Does anyone have a better idea for parsing this file? I upload the file and then read or could read before saving? Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution. It's necessary to pass the request directly to DictReader:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    data = self.request.data.get('datafile')
    reader = csv.DictReader(data, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        print row['customer']
```

Answer (score 0):

`FieldFile` is the data stored on a `FileField`. If you're looking to open it using the Python `open` method, you should instead be calling [`FieldFile.open()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.open). The error is coming from within your post-save signal handler, because [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) expects the name of a file and you are passing in a `FieldFile`.

Comment: Thanks! The solution is to pass the file on request directly to the DictReader.